# mixing CSS formatting in a single line

Tags: html, css

How's the standard way to mix two different text formats using CSS style sheets? I am trying the following

```
<span 
class="cv-first">University of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign </span> <span 
class="cv-first-right">Aug. 26<sup>th</sup> 2010</span>
```

where in the style sheet I put:

```
.cv-first
{
    font-variant:small-caps;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #000000;
}
.cv-first-right
{
    font-variant:small-caps;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #000000;
    text-align:right;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

But this doesn't work.

**UPDATE**

So I found that if I replace

```
text-align:right;
```

by

```
float: right;
```

I get exactly what I was looking for. So now the second part is on the right of the page.

Comment: Works here - http://jsfiddle.net/DuekR/

Comment: It should work, you're doing something else wrong.

Comment: Could it be that I'm within a massive block of other formatting stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPAN is inline element : it is treated as part of the text **aligned** in block container

DIV is block element: it can be **floated** left or right, whereas its text contents is **aligned**

Inline elements have no width, therefore text-align has no sense. You may override this behavior by declaring it as block element and setting the width:

```
.cv-first-right {
  display: block; /* necesarry for applying width */
  width: 150px; /* default width is 100% */
  float: right; /* move the 150px to the right side */
  text-align: right; /* align text in those 150px right */
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually had problems right-aligning the text so changing to div solved the issue.

Comment: Then you should accept the answer to get others know that the problem was solved. As I looked into your profile, you haven't accepted anything yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
.cv-first, .cv-first-right
{
    font-variant:small-caps;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #000000;
}
.cv-first-right
{
    text-align:right;
    font-style: italic;
}
```